# Drawing canvas on framelayout

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a frame layout with a background image.I am using canvas to draw lines on this framelayout.
The issue is , on different screen sizes , the lines are not appearing at the same place.

I tried multiplying the coordinates by the screen density dpi , but its still not working.

**Snippet of my canvas code**

```
paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) zoom_lay.getBackground()).getBitmap();
mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
zoom_lay.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mutableBitmap));

final Path pathPolygon_2 = new Path();
pathPolygon_2.reset(); // only needed when reusing this path for a new build
canvas.drawLine(500,500,600,615,paint);
```

Thank you

Comment: You are always drawing on the same location, obviously on different pixels screens it will appear in different locations. On a screen of 1000px height it will be in the middle while on a 2000px height screen it will be on the top 1/4

Comment: Okay , how can I make it fit on all screen sizes ?

Comment: If it's still relevant, create your layout to fill the screen and then, when you are working on it's background image, you can calculate the locations needed based on either screen size of bitmap size. If this answers what you need let me know I'll post an example

Comment: Yes please give me an example.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your layout with the following params:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/background"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Can be any type, FrameLayout is just an example. The important part is to set it's width and height to match parent.
From there you can use your code to get the bitmap and draw on it only thing, let's say you want to draw the line horizontally in the center:

```
canvas.drawLine(0,muteableBitmap.getHeight()/2,muteableBitmap.getWidth(),muteableBitmap.getHeight()/2,paint);
```

And say you want a line vertically from the center:

```
canvas.drawLine(muteable.getWidth()/2,0,muteableBitmap.getWidth()/2,muteableBitmap.getHeight,paint);
```

I've written this manually so it might not compile due to capital letters and such, but it should work

Comment: Thank you for your example.It seems to be working , but lets say I want to put a line on specific places on the screen , how do I measure it ?

Comment: Assuming your picture is taking the whole screen, you can calculate it based on it's width and height. For instance, let's say you want a line starting at the 1/4X 1/4Y corner ending at the 3/4X 3/4Y corner:
canvas.drawLine(muteable.getWidth()*0.25, muteable.getHeight()*0.25,muteable.getWidth()*0.75,muteable.getHeight()*0.75, paint) and such

Comment: Do you know if its possible to clear the drawn line on the canvas ?

Comment: Well, you simply draw over it with a line of the same color as the background, make a line thicker

Answer (score 1):

first you need to get the size of the Bitmap, and then calculate the end points of the line according to your needs. For example, if you want to draw a line in the middle of the Bitmap, the Y coordinate is this Bitmap.getHeight() * 0.5f. I hope I can help you.

```
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        int height = mutableBitmap.getHeight();
        int width = mutableBitmap.getWidth();
        float startX = width * 0f;
        float startY = height * 0.5f;
        float stopX = width * 1f;
        float stopY = height * 0.5f;
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
```

Comment: Thank you for your example.It seems to be working , but lets say I want to put a line on specific places on the screen , how do I measure it ?